# How to efficiently check for a proper sequence of files?

Tags: java, directory-structure

I need to check a directory for the presence of a sequence of files.

For example at the root directory, the requirement is that if there's a file named: `love.dat`, then there should be 3 files related to it such that there are:

```
love_p.dat
love_r.dat
love_q.dat
```

Of course, the directory contains other files as well and directories too. But no file related to another is located in different directories. So if `love.dat` is at the root directory all its related files are in the root directory too.

I'm using java btw and all other information available to me is the list of base file names with relations (e.g. in the above scenario, `love` is stored in the list of base files as the string `love`)

Comment: This will be closed as "Not programming related" if you don't tell us what environment and programming/scripting language you're using. *P.S. that isn't a threat, I'm simply predicting how the community will react to your question. It is unanswerable in this form*

Comment: Agreed. Do you need to do this in a program? BASH? Is the problem that you need to check if the related files exist? Please clarify the question.

Comment: Could you include some code showing how you've tried to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Pseudocode:

```
def check_directory(directory):
  """Returns whether the directory has all the required names."""
  names = ["love.dat", "love_p.dat", "love_r.dat", "love_q.dat"]
  return all(os.path.exists(os.path.join(directory, x) for x in names))
```

In particular, note this uses "smarter" filename manipulation by using a path joining method (which is OS-specific), but it is extremely likely normal string manipulation would work fine for that here; plus note it tests for the existence of these names — how to do that depends on your exact environment and language — while the rest is just boilerplate to set that up.

If "love" is a stem instead of literal name, you need to add it dynamically to the list of names:

```
def check_directory(directory, stem):
  """Returns whether the directory has all the required names."""
  names = [stem + x for x in [".dat", "_p.dat", "_r.dat", "_q.dat"]]
  return all(os.path.exists(os.path.join(directory, x) for x in names))

print check_directory("/", "love")  # example use
```

And if you want to check for all possible stems in a given directory, you simply need to loop over the names in that directory:

```
def find_file_groups(directory):
  """Returns groups of files as tuples of (base, _p, _r, _q)."""
  for name in os.listdir(directory):
    if name.endswith(".dat"):  # apply more filters if required
      base = name[:-4]  # remove .dat
      names = tuple(base + x for x in [".dat", "_p.dat", "_r.dat", "_q.dat"])
      if all(os.path.exists(os.path.join(directory, x) for x in names)):
        yield names
```

Comment: Now that you've updated the question to say you're using Java, my above pseudocode may not apply, but I'm leaving it at least until there's a better answer in case it does help.